# Why Ionic Framework Doesn't Support Tablet Layout on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, ionic-framework

I have a big problem with ionic framework after compile with platform android to release on Play Store such as warning message from play store about doesn't compatible with tablet layout. You can check my screenshots below:

1. Warning Message on Play Store Developer Console:
   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. They said only designed for phones:
   [image: they said only designed for phones]

When I tested on my tablet, I didn't get any problem anything and fit for tablet layout except got problem like screenshots above. How I can fix it?

You can download my application [on this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipbox.infopuskesmasjakarta)